# php: Adding status 2

Tags: php

Anyone can help me with this, i have here status 0 and status 1 now

**Status 0**: Not my friend

**Status 1**: My friend

And i need

**Status 2**: ADDED TO FRIEND LIST (we send friend request but row status is 0)

Please check query bellow...

```
<? 
$query = "SELECT * 
            FROM friends 
           WHERE (idusers={$_SESSION[userid]} 
                 AND idusers_friend={$row[ID]}) 
                 AND status='1' OR (idusers={$row[ID]} 
                 AND idusers_friend={$_SESSION[userid]} 
                 AND status='1' )";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$check_exist = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($check_exist >= 1) { ?>

 STATUS 1 - SEND A MESSSAGES (friend)

<? } elseif($check_exist == 0) { ?> 

 STATUS 0 - ADD AS FRIND (not friend)

<? } ?>
```

What i need now, i need to have **status 2** , example above you can see im make now if users is my frind i can send a messages to this user, is not in my frind list i have button to add it, but when i click to add as frind im send request (something like on facebook) and than this is status 2, waiting for accept.

*Example:* If i have this user as my frind Status in database is 1, is not in my list database is empty, if im send request row status is 0 and whan 2nd user accept request status will be changed to 1.

Comment: To make this clearer, use constants instead of having 1 and 0 as magic numbers.

Comment: If you're happy that this is solved, you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (guessing abit about your DB schema - provide table details if this doesn't work):

```
$query = "SELECT status
            FROM friends 
           WHERE idusers={$_SESSION[userid]} 
             AND idusers_friend={$row[ID]} ";

mysql_connect("hostname", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("mydb");

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {

    $status = $row->status;

    switch ($status) {

        case 0:
            // STATUS 0 - ADD AS FRIEND (not friend)
            break;

        case 1: 
            // STATUS 1 - SEND A MESSAGE (friend)
            break;

        case 2: 
            // New status
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, it't not work, here is screen from table friends http://i.imgur.com/XhbcU.png

Comment: Only this im found in logs 



`Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result`

Comment: try adding this to get a better error message: echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . "\n"; Where $link is your mysql connection.

Comment: `SELECT status FROM friends WHERE idusers=38 AND idusers_friend=134`    

query is okey as i can see also im try    

`$query = "SELECT status FROM friends WHERE idusers={$_SESSION[userid]}  AND idusers_friend={$row[ID]} OR (idusers={$row[ID]} AND idusers_friend={$_SESSION[userid]} ";`    
 
But again doesn't work

Comment: Edited to add mysql connection details. Please make sure your connection is working OK first.

Comment: It's not a problem with mysql connection, site working fine, something is wrong with this code, when i delete `while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {`  i have now always `case 0:
               echo "STATUS 0";
            break;`  but whit your code i dont have any result..hmm